# Command-line / Virtual terminal issue

Tags: command-line, virtual-terminal

I've recently got into Ubuntu, still learning using the terminal. I decided to try initiating the command-line on boot by editing boot commands to `quiet splash text` or `quiet splash nomodeset` only to find that neither works. I've tried starting the virtual terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F(1-6)</kbd> - again, with no success. Using the `text` line, I get a blank black screen on boot. Using the `nomodeset` line, I get a somewhat random color on my screen. CTRL + ALT + F(1-6) goes into a blank black screen as well, similar to the `text` boot. I've tried suggested fixes , however, with no success. Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Try removing the `vt.handoff` option.

Answer (score 1):

by **pressing shift on starting**, boot and from grub menu select **recover mode** and drop to **root shell prompt**.

open /etc/default/grub as and add text to the

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

And in the file, change this line:

**GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"**

Then update your Grub

```
update-grub
```

and

```
reboot
```

Your system will then boot to text mode.

If you once want to use GUI you can easly make light works

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

hope this will work for you

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/20348-ubuntu-login-to-text-mode-without-removing-gui

Comment: I've already tried this, however, thank you for the quick response, @ptheo. After boot, I am prompted to a blank screen again. Discovered recovery mode prompts to a blank screen as well. Really desperate atm.